# Equivalent query MagicalRecord -> Realm.io

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, predicate, magicalrecord, realm

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent expression in Realm.io for this query? I need results grouped by "dreamDate" property

```
// Search all dreams grouped by date
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@ AND parseSyncDeleted == false", user];

NSFetchedResultsController *groups = [Dream MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"dreamDate.dateWithoutTime"
                                                   withPredicate:predicate
                                                        sortedBy:@"dreamDate"
                                                       ascending:YES];

return groups;
```

**dreamDate** -> NSDate property

**dateWithoutTime** -> Category that converts it to NSDate without time components

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Realm doesn't have a built-in data structure to group results, but you can do this very easily and efficiently by holding an NSArray or NSDictionary of RLMResults. See the GroupedTableView example of how to do this: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/objc/GroupedTableView/TableViewController.m